# openshift DIY, 503 error after deleting and adding again testrubyserver.ruby file

Tags: ruby, openshift, http-status-code-503

I am trying openshift DIY cartridge. I use a windows system to manage the server from command line. I managed to run a simple html5 website. I have deleted the testrubyserver.ruby file from the webpage folder for test purposed and then added it again to my webfolder. Now i have 503 error. No restart, no stop, no start helps. I am stuck in 503. Does anyone know what to do? How can I make the testrubyserver.ruby run again?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. I checked the log file in the folder: app-root / logs. There I found out that

nohup: failed to run command `/..//testrubyserver.rb': Permission denied

I change in filezilla the permissions for the file from rw to rwx to execute it. Restarted the server and then it worked.

I do not know if this is the right approach. At least it makes my app running again.